# Sum spesific column and show other column on mysql

Tags: php, mysql, group-by, sum

I have a table like below, how to "sum" **qty** column and "group by" **productId** with show other column? im still newbie on mysql

```
id     |  productId  | invoice  | qty  | price  
-------------------------------------------------
1      |  1          | INV-01   | 2    | 1000    
2      |  2          | INV-01   | 3    | 2000             
3      |  1          | INV-01   | 1    | 1000          
4      |  2          | INV-01   | 1    | 2000         
5      |  3          | INV-02   | 1    | 3000             
6      |  3          | INV-02   | 2    | 3000             
7      |  4          | INV-02   | 2    | 4000
```

My Expectation:

```
productId  | invoice  | qty  | price  
-------------------------------------------------
1          | INV-01   | 3    | 1000    
2          | INV-01   | 4    | 2000                            
3          | INV-02   | 3    | 3000                        
4          | INV-02   | 2    | 4000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by product id, then give the list of fields you want. In the following case, it would show productId, the invoice number with the max value for given product id, sum of the qty for product id, and the max value of price for product id.

```
SELECT productId, max(invoice) as invoice, sum(qty) as qty, max(price) as price
FROM table #replace with table's name
GROUP BY productId
```

Comment: why use max while the contents are the same? or is the rule like that?

Comment: Use max because you want to tell MySQL how to get a value from the many values of invoice for a single product id (say product id is present in two different invoices)

Comment: And please mark as correct answer if you feel it helped :)